# WSDL generation with String Restriction

Tags: java, wsdl

I have a Getter/Setter method in a class like this:

```
 public class milestone { 
     String milestoneType; 
     public String getMilestoneType() 
       { 
             return milestoneType; 
       } 
     public void setMilestoneType(String milestoneType)  
       {     
            this.milestoneType = milestoneType; 
       }
    }
```

and for this generated WSDL with help of weblogic server like :

```
    <xs:complexType name="MileStone">
   <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="MilestoneType" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Now i need to restrict the milestoneType based on two values.I mean this will allow only 2 values, need to restrict other than that 2 values.

How can i change the getter/setter class for this ? please help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use an `enum` which has only the two values you want to allow, like so:

```
public enum MilestoneType {
    PRECOMMIT,
    POSTCOMMIT
}
```

Next you need to change your `Milestone` class to use this type instead of the `String`, like so:

```
public class Milestone {
    private MilestoneType milestoneType; 
    public MilestoneType getMilestoneType()  { 
        return milestoneType; 
    } 
    public void setMilestoneType(MilestoneType milestoneType) {     
        this.milestoneType = milestoneType; 
    }
}
```

Comment: public enum milestoneType { PRECOMMIT, POSTCOMMIT }  public String getMilestoneType() {
  return milestoneType;
 }
 public void setMilestoneType(String milestoneType) {
  this.milestoneType = milestoneType;
 }

Still WSDL not getting chnaged..

Comment: Thats because your enum is invisible from the wsdl point of view, you need to modify the method to get/set a milestoneType not a String.

Comment: MAde the changes au u told. whild building in eclipse error coming as
[ERROR] - Enum Types are not supported on a JWS: com.verizon.provctl.deliverymanager.model.MileStoneOrderDTM$MilestoneType
     [jwsc] D:\DM\May\dm_2013\projects\DM-war\src\com\verizon\provctl\deliverymanager\DTMMilestone.java 16:42
     [jwsc] [WARNING] - The type com.verizon.provctl.deliverymanager.model.MileStoneOrderDTM$MilestoneType used in the return on method retriveOrderMilestoneForDTM has no default constructor and might not be able to be bound to XML.

Comment: Based on the error message, I guess you're using some Weblogic plugin. Is this an Ant task or a Maven plugin at work? You might want to check out configuring the `type` of bindings being generated. Check issue [MWEBLOGIC-27](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWEBLOGIC-27) for some directions.